# How to position and calculate distances for elements in one-page scrolling websites?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm trying to hand-code one of those one-page scrolling websites.  As an example: http://titicraig.com/

I can't share the exact code I have here but the overall idea is that I'm trying to place a chevron at the bottom of the first page which, when clicked, will scroll down to the second page.  In addition, links at the top right will scroll down to their respective pages too.

What I'm having trouble with is how to place the chevron such that it is consistently at the bottom of the first page (above the fold) regardless of screen resolution?  In addition, do I manually set a height for the CSS for each page to be the height of the page regardless of screen resolution?  I am not sure how to go about doing this.

```
<body>
    <section id="first-page">
        //content
        <span class="chevron-wrapper"></span>
    </section>

    <section id="second-page">
        //content
    </section>

    <section id="third-page">
        //content
    </section>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    align: 100%;
}

#first-page
{
    /* is this even right? or should I do screen.height instead */
    /* or should it be a set pixel value? If so, how will it accommodate different resolutions? */
    height: 100%; 
}

#second-page
{
    height: 100%; 
}

#third-page
{
    height: 100%; 
}

.chevron-wrapper /* Should be at bottom of first page */
{
    margin-top: 15%; /* separation from first-page content but I found that doing this percentage-wise gets wider and wider as the page size increases */
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any help in regards to positioning things would be great.  Thanks!

Edit: I discovered `vh` so I can set `min-height: 100vh` to be 100% of the screen height regardless of resolution.  I still need help with positioning that chevron, though.

Comment: It actually scrolls to target divs..using jquery scrollTo function

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which does that!

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function() { 
      location.href = target.selector; 
      }, 501); 
         setTimeout(closeMenu,510);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
});
```

Comment: This determines the distance from current DIV content to top body portion; **scrollTop: target.offset().top** and this determines to which DIV should it scroll when clicked over a link; **location.href = target.selector**

Comment: Thank you, but I already know how to do the smooth scrolling.  What I need help on is the positioning of the chevron and page height issues.